# AWS EB deployment issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js app to Elastic Beanstalk. The app is locally working properly. However, when I try to deploy, I get the error:

```
Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
```

Here is a screenshot of the EB log for more detail:
[image]

Error Log (I found it interesting that I got permission denied - what could that mean?):

```
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
  npm ERR! path /tmp/.npm/node-linux-x64
  npm ERR! code EACCES
  npm ERR! errno -13
  npm ERR! syscall mkdir

  npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/.npm/node-linux-x64'
  npm ERR!     at Error (native)
  npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/.npm/node-linux-x64'
  npm ERR!     at Error (native)
  npm ERR!   errno: -13,
  npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
  npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
  npm ERR!   path: '/tmp/.npm/node-linux-x64',
  npm ERR!   parent: 'node' }
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
  npm ERR! Linux 4.9.58-18.55.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install" "--no-save" "node-linux-x64@9.2.0"
  npm ERR! node v6.11.5
  npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
  npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.487421323
  npm ERR! code EACCES
  npm ERR! errno -13
  npm ERR! syscall open

  npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.487421323'
  npm ERR!     at Error (native)
  npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.487421323'
  npm ERR!     at Error (native)
  npm ERR!   errno: -13,
  npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
  npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
  npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.487421323' }
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node/npm-debug.log
  module.js:471
      throw err;
      ^

  Error: Cannot find module 'node-linux-x64/package.json'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
      at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:18:27)
      at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)

  npm ERR! Linux 4.9.58-18.55.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "rebuild"
  npm ERR! node v6.11.5
  npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! node@9.2.0 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the node@9.2.0 preinstall script 'node installArchSpecificPackage'.
  npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
  npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     node installArchSpecificPackage
  npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
  npm ERR!     npm bugs node
  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls node
  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "latest",
    "express": "latest",
    "node": "latest",
    "nodemailer": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

Why does this happen?

EDIT: Added package.json and error log as requested.

Comment: So what do the log files say?

Comment: Please post your `package.json`, at least the scripts section

Comment: Edited my post with both log and package.json

Comment: Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With no information to go off, here are some guesses:

- You are manually zipping and uploading your app. [Use the CLI tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html), for some reason `eb deploy` always goes smoother
- You are on a very tiny instance and you need to upgrade to one with enough memory to handle your dependencies

If these don't help, please post your `package.json`. Or, just use [Up](https://up.docs.apex.sh/), it's so much easier than Beanstalk.

Comment: What are these CLI tools you are talking about? I only saw options for manually uploading apps in the EB deployment process.

Comment: Here is a tutorial using the EB CLI with Node https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html

Comment: I tried using CLI, and it still doesn't appear to work. I think the issue is primarily in the EACCS permission denial.